# navigational access in both directions. what does it mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I read jpa documentation and doesn't understand what does it mean?

Maybe you can show example for understanding?

Comment: Do you mean in respect to bidirectional relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two enties

```
public class Author {
    public List<Book> books;
}

public class Book {
    public Author author;
}
```

You have a bidirectional relationship. Navigational access simply means that you can get the other entity by simply following (accessing) the object

```
Author author = authorDao.findById(1);
Book main = author.books.get(0);
```

But also

```
Book book = bookDao.findByName("Dune");
Author author = book.author;
```

*(...ignoring good practice of java beans)*

Answer (score 0):

In both directions means that if you have 2 types of records : for example powerplug and electrical device that the plug knows which device is connected and the device knows in which plug it is connected.

Typical is also in a n-1 relationship: employee & company, the employee knows which company he is working for and the company knows all of its employees

This is typically resulting in a foreign key in both tables, but also querying the database is sometimes applied.